# Get one index from multiindexed dataframe

Tags: python, list, pandas, indexing

If I have a multiindexed dataframe, how can i get the information in just one of the indexes?

If my df is this:

```
first  second
bar    one       0.469112
       two      -0.282863
baz    one      -1.509059
       two      -1.135632
foo    one       1.212112
       two      -0.173215
qux    one       0.119209
       two      -1.044236
```

I would like a list of the values in index `first`. I'm used to doing something like this:

```
df.index.tolist()
```

which returns:

```
['bar','baz','foo','qux']
```

Comment: @akashkarothiya the output is returned list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`pd.Index.get_level_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html). Here's a demo:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 'B', 1], ['A', 'C', 2], ['X', 'Y', 3], ['X', 'Z', '4']],
                  columns=['idx1', 'idx2', 'value'])

df = df.set_index(['idx1', 'idx2'])

res = df.index.get_level_values(0).tolist()

['A', 'A', 'X', 'X']
```

Comment: Maybe I overlook the question , seems like he need the levels, am i right ?

Comment: @Wen, Hmm, you might be actually. We'll see.. I read that he wants the equivalent of `df.index.tolist()` but for one level.

Comment: Yeah this is exactly what I was looking for. The equivalent of `df.index.tolist()`.

Answer (score 3):

Data from jpp

```
df.index.levels[0]
Out[412]: Index(['A', 'X'], dtype='object', name='idx1')
```

Update :

```
[x[0] for x in df.index.tolist()]
Out[417]: ['A', 'A', 'X', 'X']
```

Comment: Notice you can add tolist at the end `df.index.levels[0].tolist()
`